# Python: How to scrape Facebook posts loaded by ajax (page scroll)

Tags: python, ajax, facebook

I try to scrape Facebook posts loaded by ajax (page scroll) in search.
I use Grab and requests for this.

Authorization using Grab is working, then i try to emulate scroll request, produced by browser and send it via post to load next bunch of results.
The error in response html is: "Sorry, your request cannot be loaded"

Here is code (big code because huge facebook request).

```
import requests
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
class FacebookScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {
        "view":"list",
        "encoded_query":"{\"bqf\":\"keywords_top(\\u0025D0\\u0025BB\\u0025D0\\u0025B0\\u0025D0\\u0025B2\\u0025D0\\u0025B0\\u0025D0\\u0025BB\\u0025D1\\u00258C+\\u0025D0\\u0025BF\\u0025D0\\u0025BE\\u0025D1\\u002582\\u0025D0\\u0025BE\\u0025D0\\u0025BA)\",\"vertical\":\"content\",\"post_search_vertical\":None,\"intent_data\":\"{\\\"intent\\\":\\\"posts\\\",\\\"entity_id\\\":None,\\\"sub_intents\\\":{\\\"user\\\":True},\\\"user_confidence\\\":0.2384902536869,\\\"typeahead_user_confidence\\\":0.69785696268082,\\\"quel_topics\\\":[],\\\"multi_label_intents\\\":[{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0113326292485},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":6.7988303271704e-6},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0008767499239184},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.025693353265524},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.010204718448222},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0020656401757151},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.01333892159164},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0087564773857594},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0016323747113347},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0084763253107667},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.015831520780921},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.004807879216969},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.058732055127621},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.033020552247763},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0066938307136297},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0071515664458275},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.57516884803772},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.21925939619541},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0026327867526561},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0046313949860632},{\\\"value\\\":True,\\\"confidence\\\":0.0015605170046911}],\\\"annotated_string\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"entities\\\\\\\":[],\\\\\\\"segments\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\u003Cusername>\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"tokens\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\u043b\\\\\\\\u0430\\\\\\\\u0432\\\\\\\\u0430\\\\\\\\u043b\\\\\\\\u044c \\\\\\\\u043f\\\\\\\\u043e\\\\\\\\u0442\\\\\\\\u043e\\\\\\\\u043a\\\\\\\"}]}\\\"}\",\"filters\":[],\"has_chrono_sort\":False,\"query_analysis\":\"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\",\"subrequest_disabled\":False}",
        "encoded_title":"WyJcdTAwMjVEMFx1MDAyNUJCXHUwMDI1RDBcdTAwMjVCMFx1MDAyNUQwXHUwMDI1QjJcdTAwMjVEMFx1MDAyNUIwXHUwMDI1RDBcdTAwMjVCQlx1MDAyNUQxXHUwMDI1OEMrXHUwMDI1RDBcdTAwMjVCRlx1MDAyNUQwXHUwMDI1QkVcdTAwMjVEMVx1MDAyNTgyXHUwMDI1RDBcdTAwMjVCRVx1MDAyNUQwXHUwMDI1QkEiXQ",
        "ref":"unknown",
        "logger_source":"www_main",
        "typeahead_sid":"",
        "tl_log":False,
        "impression_id":"ed9cde39",
        "filter_ids":{
            "1597273353820386:1674330276114693:0":"1597273353820386:1674330276114693:0"
        },
        "experience_type":"grammar",
        "exclude_ids":None,
        "browse_location":"",
        "trending_source":None,
        "reaction_surface":None,
        "reaction_session_id":None,
        "ref_path":"/search/top/",
        "is_trending":False,
        "topic_id":None,
        "place_id":None,
        "story_id":None,
        "callsite":"browse_ui:init_result_set",
        "has_top_pagelet":True,
        "display_params":{
            "mrss":True
        },
        "cursor":"Abp0rWq8oGjiUWYmIeN9rZCuAXTubQ9beY7hyGlZpau3ekEF9BSelQe85TthKUvpoNEU65kQorg_Fya3xI47JPWGoJ-lNMS4JiOobTZ0Q3tP0HD1Z5JZiCLbT10PwrRNibnv-TKdTBhwtfMvqR816Hd9vIHPRxCBmT5lPfrVZC7f0ohVLeSCKFEYmP-47IiDsWW1YynB8Yqr_54b7iIQWB4uixrp5Zm5AHrCilxpqGtp9ye5Y2nKCyK8UtMkzzQ11CTfidmPmDMPQgU3rFroTvpUc96QGvfX1pNjNw3sn-CFyn5TLq_0mX_jOVP8BzfRP7qhnmcmjs3Rf2_l22Q9C-gQGqSwDUqE63XszHUYqEW5e-KtU_3Hcpb3OT0MJyZ7EQI",
        "page_number":2,
        "em":False,
        "mr":False,
        "tr":None
    }

    def scrape(self):
        posts = self.scrape_posts()
        for post in posts:
            print ("Фейсбучный пост ", post)

    def scrape_posts(self, max_pages=4):      
        posts = []
        pageno = 2

        cursor = [
            'AbocHlVuS3n0hW0t-IUaCGN9y1jZzVg_cbHqG4IPXcnKhfacxLL52L4S1fMLklQPLgIBtRBA6z_hRaeCS0xzr1BCZbBe8fIdpVYMegK7Ye2TxzWSNRWUEJC0IMYWCjEkZQvI-Ix_Kx_E0Kx1oap8jGJAN9housnxkkAq8_ElwDTK9TbaHr0TB1MNNwR4lQU2PKYXOWajSG_0_AZ2DOCsn-DIMHL4jbhnhrwps_2kIi0gaC6y3aqbp9q8iILcwbXsjUzsTQce3tr3U9GQdVFClJQf2guaIwNa7KSmTEM99-SeNAMC07e8-VTCAd5Uc01qSa4yW_Asfl27xsXKbv9Aa5JBMt7fB8fvo1OBpOrU43Zg-lb1C7wAKoeqmo6bp2VfHVw',
            'Abo8hIfmoANZ0PCtYHB4ooCJ59SHjd5JoFmxoE2nu99WKD5kwB8riOnI6OiqTTO3gnI2Gehgu8BONQytNPKWWgBPnOTV7OF1Rlwmp2bEO5tQfDEw3Vcjiy_X3QJe2bj74E-DV2qom6G75bL4tRa-zPi4JcGYOGWvBTFTabTHJR8fWIAK1NctX4_lztV-aaGAZanQvrcDKFP9gz7w5luvOo4Lv6eN4xfGlJwoEmyj9blI-EG1Ijc3lhKXrHse0hPSJlKaWVo4w1lkijdeJE1QyzW-WRtaGbm6FTLDrFaOeOnLp8g6LhS3nJ2X2yx6-9967VQbNtWUQ2dCs3QqomitMMuXkDb-B3ASJmtRc4krWmpi0-hN46Si2r_ntU4cSt5idmg'
        ]
        dyn = [
            '7AmajEzUGByA5Q9UoGya4A5EWq2W8GAdy8Z9LFwxBxCbzES2N6xybxu13wHgf8jyR88y8aGjzEgDKuEjKeCwxxW3Ouum2SUpGqewIUsz8nxm3a229yoOm8yUgx62q78vDw',
            '7AmajEzUGByA5Q9UoGya4A5EWq2W8GAdy8Z9LFwxBxvyUWdwIhEoyUnwgUaQ3O4UJi28y2GAUW49XDG4XzFE8ouwYDDBwJK6qCzEbe78O5UlwOwwyoCcBy8K48hwCxO7VU'
        ]
        req = [
            'q',
            'y'
        ]

        self.data['page_number'] = pageno

        while pageno < max_pages:
            #self.data['cursor'] = cursor[pageno-2]
            payload = {
                'data': json.dumps(self.data),
                '__dpr': 1,
                '__user':100012747062538,
                '__a':1,
                '__dyn':'7AmajEzUGByA5Q9UoGya4A5EWq2WiWF3oyfirWo8popyUWdwIhEoyUnwgUat0Hx24UJi28y2GAUW49XDG4XzFE8ouwh9VobrxCFEW2PxOcxu5pUaE88C9z9oybx24oqyUsx-u6vU',
                #'__dyn':dyn[pageno-2],
                '__req':8,
                '__be':-1,
                '__pc':'PHASED:DEFAULT',
                '__rev':2467498
            }

            #grab.cookies.load_from_file('cookies.html')
            url='https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?init=quick&q=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&tas=0.715880302462869'
            g = Grab(url=url, cookiefile='cookies.html', post=payload)
            g.go(url=url)
            r = g.response.unicode_body()
            """
           post =
           r = requests.post(
               url='https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?init=quick&q=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&tas=0.715880302462869',
               data=payload,
               #    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
               #}
           )
           """

            print ("---------------------- ↓r ", pageno , "↓ ------------------")
            print(r)
            print ("---------------------- ↑r ", pageno , "↑ ------------------")


            # Next page
            pageno += 1
            self.data['page_number'] = pageno

        return posts

def grab_demo(request):

    # search page to scrape
    page = "https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?init=quick&q=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&tas=0.715880302462869"
    # id of user
    parser_user_id = 100012747062538
    # 
    page_number = 1


    # Логинимся в фейсбуке
    grab = Grab(log_file='out.html')
    grab.go('https://www.facebook.com/')

    grab.set_input("email", "your_email_here")
    grab.set_input("pass", "your_password_here")
    grab.submit()
    s1 = grab.response.unicode_body()
    grab.dump_cookies('cookies.html')

    print ("---------------------- Login done ------------------")
    print(s1)
    # Login done


    scraper = FacebookScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

I think the problem in this part:

```
        g = Grab(url=url, cookiefile='cookies.html', post=payload)
        g.go(url=url)
        r = g.response.unicode_body()
```

Who can help? Also, i dont want use Selenium because it produces real browser to launch.

Comment: instead of Selenium, you can try phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/) , it will act as a virtual browser

Comment: Facebook does not like to be scraped. They have all kind of measures in place to prevent and complicate it. These measure can change multiple times a days. A scraper from today is not guaranteed to work tomorrow. To access Facebook posts use their API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ with a library (aka SDK) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks#third-party-sdks

Comment: @KlausD. - i know that, we use python facebook sdk for other tasks. But it is impossible to scrape search posts via API, Facebook switched off this

Comment: @userxxx thanks, but thi is javascript, we need python version

Comment: @VicNicethemer - its JS but you can automate it using python. I have used  it for same purpose.

Comment: @VicNicethemer you can use headless webkit in selenium. as in phantomjs. and also good luck with facebook scraping.